# Right way to swap x elements in List

Tags: list, scala, swap

I started to learn Scala language and I have a question. How do you think, is it a right way to swap first and last x elements in List in a functional style?

```
def swap(l: List[Any], x: Int) = {
  val l1 = l.take(x)
  val l2 = l.slice(x, l.length - x)
  val l3 = l.takeRight(x)
  l3 ::: l2 ::: l1
}
```

It doesn't matter what happened if x would be more than half list length. I'm interested to find out algorithm.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This code is correct and is in a reasonable functional style.  It's not the most efficient since it has to traverse the list four times to create the pieces `l1` through `l3`.  Also, you probably want to preserve the type that the list contains, so a slight improvement is:

```
def swap[A](l: List[A], x: Int) = {
  val (l1,rest) = l.splitAt(x)
  val (l2,l3) = rest.splitAt(rest.length-x)
  l3 ::: l2 ::: l1
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried it and it worked fine:

```
scala> swap(List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),2)
res0: List[Any] = List(4, 5, 3, 1, 2)
```

Is there anything wrong with the code you provided yourself?